# How to make this kind of array in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am trying to building dynamically an array of empty elements. This is what i have tried so far.

```
aData.length=5;
var noOFSeries = [];
    for (var i = 1; i <= aData.length - 1; i++) {
        noOFSeries.push([]);
    }
```

I want this kind of output `[], [], [], []` so that i can put in jqplot.

```
$.jqplot('barchartReqCat', [chartData, [], [], [], []], options);
```

replace to

```
$.jqplot('barchartReqCat', [chartData, noOFSeries], options);
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Do you actually want to push _empty arrays_ into your chart? (Maybe jqplot needs that for some reason, but it seems weird.)

Comment: jqplots are weird , they need for properly displaying legends

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There you have some ways:
`arr1` filled with [.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map);
`arr2` filled with [.fill()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-NA/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill); and
 `arr3` with [loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration).

```js
var arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 4].map(function(value) {
  return [];
});
console.log(arr1);

var arr2 = new Array(4).fill([]);
console.log(arr2);

var arr3 = [];
var length = 5;
for(var i = 0; i < 4; i++) arr3.push([]);

console.log(arr3);
```

Comment: getting 4 empty arrays but not working in jqplot..anyways thanks

Comment: After all, `noOFSeries` is `[[], [], [], []]`: an array of 4 empty arrays. `[chartData, [], [], [], []]` will be different than `[charData, noOFSeries]`. Are you concatenating `noOFSeries` with `chartData`?

Comment: var myArr = chartData.concat(noOFSeries);
    myArr; $.jqplot('barchartReqCat', [myArr], options); tried this not working

Comment: Remove `[]` of `[myArr]`, it should be `$.jqplot('barchartReqCat', myArr, options);`. With `[]`, `[myArr]` is: `[[charData, [], [], [], []]]`, not `[charData, [], [], [], []]`.

Comment: @GeekyNerd [`[chartData].concat(noOFSeries)`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48526023/3054411)

Comment: `var myArr = [chartData].concat(noOFSeries); $.jqplot('barchartReqCat', myArr, options);` This is working .Thanks https://stackoverflow.com/users/9034955/m-jr and https://stackoverflow.com/users/3054411/serge-k

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Array.prototype.fill`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill) like this:

```
let noOfSeries = Array(5).fill([]);
```

Comment: can you post full answer

Comment: @GeekyNerd That is the full answer.

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear, maybe clarify what exactly you want, so I can expand my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) or, if you want backward compatibility, you can use a new array (`myArr` in my example):

```
var aData = {
    length: 5
  },
  noOFSeries = [],
  chartData = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

for (var i = 1; i <= aData.length - 1; i++) {
  noOFSeries.push([]);
}

$.jqplot('barchartReqCat', [chartData, ...noOFSeries], options);

var myArr = [chartData].concat(noOFSeries);
$.jqplot('barchartReqCat', myArr, options);
```